# Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24) ,Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint, apt, ip

So I just now did a fresh install to Linux Mint 20, but this problem was also present in Linux Mint 19.3. Every time I try to do a `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade` or even download software from the software manager I get an error. The same thing happened when I tried to update what the update manager recommended.

I found that I can upgrade or update if I keep running the command `sudo apt-get update/upgrade` after every failed attempt. As each update/upgrade stops at a certain percentage, when I run the command again it continues from that same percentage and by doing the update/upgrade a few times it finally completes.

This is the error I get when I tried downloading VLC from the software manager. It first says:

```
Failed to download package files
Check your Internet connection.
```

And the details are :

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sdl-image1.2/libsdl-image1.2_1.2.12-12_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sidplay-libs/libsidplay2_2.1.1-15ubuntu2_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libspatialaudio/libspatialaudio0_0.3.0+git20180730+dfsg1-2build1_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/srt/libsrt1_1.4.0-1build1_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libssh2/libssh2-1_1.8.0-2.1build1_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pupnp-1.8/libupnp13_1.8.4-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
```

...and so on.

The two specific error values of error which appear everywhere are `2001:67c:1360:8001::23` and `91.189.88.152`. The software sources my machines uses right now are:

```
(Main) http://packages.linuxmint.com
(Focal) http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I tried changing the Focal sources to many different ones but no success. And I even messed up with the `source.list` files present in `/etc/apt/source.list.d` before and had to fresh install Linux due to many problems. So I really do not know what to do here and have found many others with the same problem.

Comment: Did you verify your own network isn't the problem?

Comment: You say you found many others with the same problem. It may help to add links to those problems.

Comment: @Mast how do i do this ? I am using a google wifi as a router, does that harm any way ?  other than that how do I know ?

Comment: For me it was the corporate proxy, this was my solution: sudo http_proxy=http://<ip>:<port>  https_proxy=http://<ip>:<port> apt-get update

Answer (score 6):

That looks like a misconfigured IPv6 stack. Linux thinks it has IPv6 and tries to use it (prefers it actually) to connect.

You can force `apt-get` to use IPv4 adding `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true`. For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
```

If you want to make the option permanent you can add it to a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, for example inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99only-ipv4`:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```

Comment: I did try this , and yes this works. But is there a permanent solution ?

Comment: Ok even forcing to use IPv4 gives the same error .

Comment: It works for me, but how you can make it permanent. For example, without using **-o Acquire::ForeIPv4=true**

Comment: @EdisonPebojot check the updated answer and maybe `man apt.conf` for all the details.